# ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested. Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I'm getting this exception in hibernate HQL Query:

> `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested`

I want to know, which column is causing issue. How to get this information?

I assume data conversion causing issue.

Comment: Turn on tracing in hibernate to see the raw query.

Comment: I updated to show you how you should make the error appear clearly on your post. But difficult to help you without details on what you're expecting to do: what kind of data are your retreiving / pushing from / to your database?